# When will SE 2.0 sites have the same reputation requirements as the Trilogy?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

I know a potential answer (and probably what's the official stance right now) would be *when and if it graduates to site*, but perhaps this needs further analysis.

For popular sites there are already a lot of users with 1000 rep that can vote to close, and several with 2000 that can vote to delete -- they are not numbers that hard to reach.

Should there be another metric to decide to up the rep requirements? If so, what would this metric be?

When a site has Pro Tempore moderators assigned, is it really necessary to have so many users with the ability to vote to close, delete, see flags, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Private Beta, Public Beta, and Mature Site rep thresholds are documented here:

[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the public beta as stated in their respective FAQs.

Comment: There are more questions in my post

Comment: I chose not to answer those. The betas are intended to be kind of a wild west environment.

Answer (score 0):

We needed those people with reputation badly at Gaming before pro tempore moderators started being appointed. That said, wide access to closing and reopening tools is useful to let the community fine tune its definition phase in 1st person on real data (for example, neither of gaming's and game dev's definition phases addressed mod questions.).